# Differential equations with dense solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the differential equation $P(y',y'',y''',y'''')=0$ on $\mathbb R$, where $P(x,y,z,w)$ is the homogeneous polynomial of degree $7$ given by
$$
3x^4yw^2-4x^4z^2w+6x^3y^2zw+24x^2y^4w-12x^3yz^3-29x^2y^3z^2+12y^7.
$$
This example was given by Rubel in 1981 (Bulletin of the AMS), and he proved that for any continuous functions $f,g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $g>0$ there is a solution $y$ of the differential equation satisfying
$$
|y(t)-f(t)|\le g(t),\quad \text{for all } t\in\mathbb R.
$$
Quite impressive. When one reads the proof one understands that all comes from the particular structure of the equation, but really impressive!

My question is the following:

> Is there any polynomial of smaller degree leading to the same property?

A perhaps more ambitious question would be: what is the smallest degree of a polynomial having this property? In fact one could also vary the number of variables of the polynomial.

Comment: 3 years and no responses! Seems like it's ripe for mathoverflow, possibly a research grade question

Comment: @frogeyedpeas More like 3 months? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it is paywalled, but [this paper of C. Elsner](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022247X00967301/1-s2.0-S0022247X00967301-main.pdf?_tid=40c9fb0a-0052-11e7-b2ec-00000aacb360&acdnat=1488574073_ce26f9de4d4407523d908ad908e7e0a8) claims to obtain a universal ODE out of a sixth-order polynomial equation. The title is "A Universal Differential Equation of Degree 6". The solutions of this equation are, like in Rubel's, $C^\infty$.

[Wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalDifferentialEquation.html) describes two additional families (due to Duffin and Briggs) of universal (polynomial) differential equations, the solutions of which appear to be only $C^n$ for some $n$. These families have degree 3.