# Example of DS with a dense trajectory in the whole state space

Tags: calculus, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open and connected set. We assume there is a vector field $\mathcal{C}^1(\overline{U})$ giving rise to a DS ($\overline{U}$ denotes the closure)
$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=F(\mathbf{x})$$
We set $\Gamma_{\mathbf{x}_0}=\{\mathbf{x}(t)|t \in I_{max}\}$ where $I_{max}$ is the maximal interval of existence.

---

**My question is the following:** Is there a DS/ can somebody give an example of a DS which has a dense trajectory in $\overline{U}$, i.e. $\overline{\Gamma_{x_0}}=\overline{U}$?

I am unable to come up with an example and wonder if something like that actually exists.

Comment: Not really related, but you may be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653308/differential-equations-with-dense-solutions